# How can I select the second dataframe only from a webpage with two dataframes, using pandas in python?

Tags: python, pandas, urllib2

I am trying to only use the second dataframe on this url, but I cannot figure out how to specify to only get the one dataframe. It prints out the dataframe of the chart and the table, but all I want it to print out is the table.

```
`import pandas as pd  
 import urllib.request

page = pd.read_html('https://www.google.com/finance/historical?q=a&startdate=Jan%201%2C%202000&enddate=Feb%2028%2C%202017&num=200&ei=_nm3WKGHCIf7jAG74ar4Cw&start=200', header=0)

for df in page:
    print(df)`
```

Comment: If all you want is the stock price, you can just use [`pandas datareader`](https://pandas-datareader.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) package, it can let you choose to use `yahoo` or `google` finance as your data source. Also, it returns dataframe by default, so it is much easier to work with.

Comment: Agreed that comes directly as df and avoids extra work that for surely follows getting list of data frames that above would result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The table you are looking for has a class attribute `gf-table`, pass it to `pd.read_html`, then it will only read the second table:

```
page = pd.read_html('https://www.google.com/finance/historical?q=a&startdate=Jan%201%2C%202000&enddate=Feb%2028%2C%202017&num=200&ei=_nm3WKGHCIf7jAG74ar4Cw&start=200', 
                    attrs = {'class': 'gf-table'},
                    header=0)
​
page

#             Date   Open   High    Low  Close   Volume
#0    May 12, 2016  42.59  42.94  42.42  42.73  2224506
#1    May 11, 2016  42.19  43.20  42.12  42.46  3325515
#2    May 10, 2016  41.50  42.00  41.35  42.00  2094305
#3     May 9, 2016  41.51  41.78  41.29  41.33  1741539
#4     May 6, 2016  40.86  41.62  40.72  41.43  1403476
#5     May 5, 2016  40.64  41.03  40.51  40.96  1083956
#...
```

Answer (score 0):

Using data-reader would be much better way to work with google of yahoo finance data. That said @Psidom provided correct answer.

Here is an example how you would get Agilent stock data as DataFrame directly rather than a list of dataframes by using data-reader.

```
import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader.data as web
import datetime

start = datetime.datetime(2000, 1, 1)
end = datetime.datetime(2017, 2, 27)

data = web.DataReader('A', 'google', start, end)

data.head()
```

This would directly return Pandas dataframe allowing you directly to do things like.

```
data.ix['2010-01-04']
```

To get data from spefic data for example